# How to get PayPal subscriptions based on ID

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce

I am really lost with PayPal.

When I create a subscription using PayPal buttons, my IPN gets back a `subscr_id` like `I-PA7NEN3H0AHV`. I can use Merchant SDK to look that up.

I am trying to move a WooCommerce site and all the profile ids/subscription ids look like `B-ABC2342342PA7NEN3H0AHV`.

So what is the difference between profiles that start with `I-` and `B-` and how do I get data about ones that start in `B-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Id starts with I-XXX refers PayPal recurring/subscription payment. Using this Id you will get recurring payments. This is an auto pay.
The Id starts with B-XXX refers PayPal billing agreement Payment. Using this id you can create reference transactions for charging the buyer. [Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/archive/api/merchant/GetBillingAgreementCustomerDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) for more information on getting billing agreement id customer details.

Here I am copying the PayPal MTS support page which gives more information about PayPal billing agreement API call. [Click here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1502&actp=LIST) for full details.

Comment: Is it at all possible to query Ids that start with `I-XXX` ?

Comment: You can call the API GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails for getting the details about the recurring profile ( I-XXX ). You can get only one recurring profile information at a time. Here is the more information: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: all your links are expired